# After i change table fields (add or update) in mysql, i really want to recreate all the model and CRUD facility in yii with gii?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Actually, i'm a laravel developer, recently moved to yii and i found gii was there. I can create models, controllers and CRUD facilities with gii... and that's great!

But if I a add more fields in a table or simple delete a field in a table I have to recreate model and controller with gii, otherwise it gives error. It's really taking my time. Is there any other way to do it, because I searched it and found nothing so far about it. People are suggesting command line, but using gii, is it possible?

Comment: yes you can create modules again by deleting all old files, or else you need to add those fields manually in module rules and also in related files,like views

Comment: I'm surprised you need to recreate the controllers and models every time. I've never had to do this. What errors are you getting? Surely if you add fields, you can simply use them straight away, and if you delete fields you just need to remove every reference to that field, usually in view files and in model rules. That should be all you need to do.

Comment: @NitinP i know that man! that i can delete them, but every time model, controller, view i need to update all 3 of them....it's messy!!!

Comment: @PratikRanpara : Then there is no way dude, you dont know structure of your model and want to modify it on the fly...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create a gii model again, once a new field is added.By the looks of it if you do not want to write code again then gii will give an option to modify the existing files and add the fields on its own.Simple as that.
But there is an disadvantage to this,if you have made some modifications as in for logic then that will get overridden once you modify the files using gii.But I suggested this because this fits in your business logic or as far as I can grasp it :p

Comment: of course, that is the thing!
i have lots of modification in one model, right!
suddenly, a change comes in database then i have to backup my model, then have to create a model in GII again, model gets overridden, then have to adjust my old model code in new one. so much clumsy man